# SQL min and max returning different result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, max, min

I am trying to pull in a min and max timestamp of a single session ID to do some analysis. 
What could cause MIN and MAX versions of the same SQL query be returning a (slightly) different result set? I am confused why I get a different number of results. The database is not updated in realtime. Does anyone have a possible explenation?

```
SELECT [ActivityLogs].sessionid,
       maxSelect.mxDate,
       [ActivityLogs].ClientIp INTO ##maxSessionTimes
FROM [OLBRET_COPY].[dbo].[ActivityLogs]
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT max([ActivityLogs].[DateTime]) mxDate,
          SessionId
   FROM [OLBRET_COPY].[dbo].[ActivityLogs]
   GROUP BY SessionId) maxSelect ON [ActivityLogs].SessionId = maxSelect.SessionId
AND [ActivityLogs].[DateTime] = maxSelect.mxDate
WHERE [ActivityLogs].[DateTime] > '2017-11-29'


SELECT [ActivityLogs].sessionid,
       minSelect.mxDate,
       [ActivityLogs].ClientIp INTO ##minSessionTimes
FROM [OLBRET_COPY].[dbo].[ActivityLogs]
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT min([ActivityLogs].[DateTime]) mxDate,
          SessionId
   FROM [OLBRET_COPY].[dbo].[ActivityLogs]
   GROUP BY SessionId) minSelect ON [ActivityLogs].SessionId = minSelect.SessionId
AND [ActivityLogs].[DateTime] = minSelect.mxDate
WHERE [ActivityLogs].[DateTime] > '2017-11-29'
```

Comment: The date is part of the join, so when filtering on `max` vs `min` you're filtering on different values.  Why are you expecting the same results for different queries?

Comment: @JohnLBevan I realize my initial question may not be 100% clear. I am getting a different number of results which is strange to me. The expected behavior is when the SessionID appears only once, min and max return the same date time, and when there are more than one instances of the same SessionID, then min and max are true min and max. I am not sure what you mean regarding the date being part of the join. I dont see how that affects the number of results.

Comment: We don't have your data, but generally it's quite possible for two sets of rows to have the same minimum date but different maximum date, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use min/max as window functions instead so you can use a single query:

```
SELECT
        *
FROM (
      SELECT
              *
            , MIN([DateTime]) over(partition by sessionid) minDateTime
            , MAX([DateTime]) over(partition by sessionid) maxDateTime
      FROM [OLBRET_COPY].[dbo].[ActivityLogs]
      WHERE [ActivityLogs].[DateTime] > '2017-11-29'
      ) d
WHERE [DateTime] = minDateTime or [DateTime] = maxDateTime
```